# Installing Helm 2.9 on mac osx and Tiller

Tags: macos, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm trying to install older version of helm and tiller on minikube locally and keep on getting the `Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource` erorr message - no clue on how else to approach the problem;

Steps I did:

- Accoording to this site: https://medium.com/@nehaguptag/installing-older-version-of-helm-downgrading-helm-8f3240592202

```
$ brew unlink kubernetes-helm
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/78d64252f30a12b6f4b3ce29686ab5e262eea812/Formula/kubernetes-helm.rb
$ brew switch kubernetes-helm 2.9.1
```

- Other than that just: `minikube start`
- Set kubectl to use minikube: `kubectl config set-context minikube`
- Change docker to run/download images on minikube: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

The error message i get is:

```
MacBook-Pro% helm init
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/cache
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/local
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/plugins
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/starters
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/cache/archive
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/rwalas/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

** Update

This bug report helps a little but issues still exists: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374

current workaround seems to be something like this:

`helm init --output yaml > tiller.yaml`
and update the tiller.yaml:

change to apps/v1
add the selector field

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: helm
    name: tiller
  name: tiller-deploy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helm
      name: tiller
```

and:

- `kubectl apply -f tiller.yaml`
- `helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -`

---

#### Resolved:

And these steps helped me in the end, which I suggest to everyone who want to use older versions of helm

```
# 1. Check which binary you would like: https://github.com/helm/helm/releases and copy address
wget -c https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
rm -rf ~/.helm
mv <directory_of_download>/Darwin-AMD64<or whatever other name it was named>/helm /usr/local/bin/helm
```

Comment: Could you please share the version of minikube that you are using?

Comment: ```
minikube version: v1.6.2
commit: 54f28ac5d3a815d1196cd5d57d707439ee4bb392 ```

Comment: And which Kubernetes version does it run?

Comment: hmm that's weird, when I `minikube ssh` into it it doesn't see any kubectl `kubectl version` `-bash: kubectl: command not found`

Comment: You may have to install it separately. Take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/216), it should help. Please remember to check that K8s version when you are done.

Comment: ah sorry - on the minikube there is no kubectl but on my computer I've got `$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-13T11:51:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: i `minikube delete` `minikube start` all the time test various ways people initialy configure it - but every time I get the same error - it must be related to the `$ % helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"} ` from my computer

Comment: Try to use the 1.15.4 version of K8s when starting your minikube as it was an approved workaround. `minikube delete` and than `minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.15.4`. After that `helm init`. Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: yea in the end I had wrong binary and these steps helped ```# 1. Check which binary you would like: https://github.com/helm/helm/releases and copy address
wget -c https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
rm -rf ~/.helm
mv <directory_of_download>/Darwin-AMD64<or whatever other name it was named>/helm /usr/local/bin/helm```

Comment: Great! I will compose a community wiki answer from what we have found in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. Check which binary you would like: https://github.com/helm/helm/releases and copy address
   `wget -c https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
   tar -zxvf helm-v3.0.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
   rm -rf ~/.helm
   mv <directory_of_download>/Darwin-AMD64<or whatever other name it was named>/helm /usr/local/bin/helm`
2. The newest versions of K8s got some problems with installing Helm. Try to use the 1.15.4 version of K8s when starting your minikube as it was an approved workaround. `minikube delete` and than `minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.15.4`. After that helm init.

Comment: mate, you copied first point from my post :D, only the second point brings some value so props for that

Comment: Yes, as a community wiki so I will not get any potential reputation gains for it because both your and mine solutions can make the job done. SO works in a way that official answer should be posted like that instead of question edit or written comment. I hope you are ok with that.